# Strange formatting after starting second page

Tags: tables, formatting

I got some tables in a documents. If the content inside the table fits inside one page, the spacing between lines and table arrangement are usual. However, if the content is longer, the two table will swap positions and the spacing between other lines widen.

Please check the code here https://github.com/kychanbp/HSF-Forms-Generation

Under template --> form b.

**A normal one page document**
[image: A normal one page document]

**Two page document: table order changed. Sometimes, spacing changed too**

[image: The table order is wrong]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to tex.sx! Please add a Minimal Working Example (MWE) the illustrates your problem. That is, a piece of code that can be compiled by anyone with a standard TeX distribution, so that we can check what you problem is and try to solve it.

Comment: Is this the output you expect: https://imgur.com/V5uQ3hF ?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik That's the template. If I add more content inside the table (e.g. 2 pages document), the spacing and the table arrangement will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using environment `table` which has the ability to float.  If the table fits not on the rest of the free page it simply floats to the next page.

To avoid this simply do **not** use `table`.

Remember to break manually the table into two parts if it gets longer than one page ...

To get no different spacing between the lines of your document please add command `\raggedbottom` to the preamble.

So with the following complete MWE (see marking `<======` for important code changings):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[%
  a4paper,
  top=25mm,
  bottom=10mm,
  left=32mm,
  right=32mm,
  marginparwidth=1.75cm,
  showframe % <============================ to visualize the typing area and margins
]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{soul}
%\usepackage{epsfig} % <=======================================================
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{update}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont
\bfseries\filright}{}{0em}{}
%
\titlespacing{\section}
{0pc}{*3.2}{*1.0}[0pc]

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont
\bfseries\filright}{}{0.5em}{}
%
\titlespacing{\subsection}
{0pc}{*3.2}{*0.2}[0pc]

\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{%
  labelindent=*, 
  leftmargin=*, 
  itemsep=-3pt,
  label={\makebox[0pt][l]{$\square$}\raisebox{.15ex}{\hspace{0.1em}$\checkmark$}}%
}

\newcommand{\nocheck}{\mbox{\makebox[0pt][l]{$\square$}\raisebox{.15ex}{\hspace{0.1em}{$\phantom{\checkmark}$}}}}
\parindent=0mm
\pagestyle{empty}

\raggedbottom % <=======================================================
%\flushbottom


\begin{document}

Form B

\section{Expansion of Hong Kong International Airport into a Three-Runway System}

Marine Travel Routes and Management Plan for High Speed Ferries of SkyPier

\subsection{\ul{Case Audit and Checking Record}}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
%\begin{table}[htb] % <=======================================================
\fontsize{11pt}{15pt}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{38mm}|
p{99mm}<{\raggedright}|}\hline
%%%
Reference Plan: & Marine Travel Routes and Management Plan for High Speed Ferries of SkyPier (The Plan) (EP Condition 2.10)
\\ \hline
Monitoring Data: & Ferry movement data collected in the period between
\newline
\ul{4 October 2017 to 5 October 2017}
\\[1.0mm]\hline
Information and Data Checked: &
\begin{minipage}[t]{110mm}
\begin{itemize}
\item Automatic Identification System (AIS)
\item Data Daily SkyPier HSF movements
  \item Record of potential deviations
\item Response provided by the ferry operators
\end{itemize}\vspace*{-1.5ex}
\end{minipage}
\\\hline
Case No: & \textit{SPNC-874}
\\ \hline
Date: & \textit{4 October 2017}
\\ \hline
Ferry Details: & Ferry Number: 3A167
\newline Average Speed: 13.5 knots\newline Range of Instantaneous Speed: 13 -- 14 knots\newline Duration of Instantaneous Speeding: 2
\\ \hline
Comments and Observations \newline From ET: & Insufficient AIS data was recorded. The AIS signals could not be received which might due to interference effect. Based on available AIS data, the speed and route of vessel could not be analyzed whether it had any deviation within the Speed Control Zone (SCZ). Vessel captain has provided the AIS plots which indicated the vessel entered the SCZ though the gate access point and no speeding in the SCZ was observed. Ferry operator should investigate the reason for the AIS failure and check the AIS system to ensure that sufficient data points can be received. \\ \hline
Comments and Observations\newline From IEC Marine Advisor: & FUXk
\\ \hline
Reason(s) valid\\ according to \\ The Plan? &
\begin{minipage}[t]{95mm}
\begin{itemize}
\item Yes (case closed)
\item[\nocheck] No (The ET to confirm with AA MCDD on the required follow up actions)
\end{itemize}\vspace*{-1.5ex}
\end{minipage}
\\\hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{table} % <=======================================================
}


{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{:L{23mm}:L{35mm}:L{35mm}:L{35mm}:}
\hdashline
\Gape[14pt]{}& \makecell[l]{ET Leader /\\[2mm]
ET's Representative} &
\makecell[l]{IEC/ \\[2mm]
IEC's Representative} &
\makecell[l]{PM /\\[2mm]
PM's Representative} \\ \hline
Signature &\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{sig1.pdf}
&  &  \\ \hdashline
Name & Terence Kong &  &
\Gape[10pt]{}
\\\hdashline
\end{tabular}
}


\end{document}
```

you get:

[image: first page]

and:

[image: second page]

Comment: Yes. It works. but how can I remove the lines around the table?